# Hello, I stopped the postgresql process and i don't know how to reopen it

Tags: sql, eclipse, postgresql

Please give me complete tutorial  because i am new. I know it's dumb question but please help me

Comment: also where should i use $ postgres -D /usr/local/pgsql/data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/server-start.html

> Before anyone can access the database, you must start the database server. The database server program is called `postgres`. The `postgres` program must know where to find the data it is supposed to use. This is done with the `-D` option. Thus, the simplest way to start the server is:
>
> ```
> $ postgres -D /usr/local/pgsql/data
> ```

Comment: where should i use this command